# How to increase lightness of color jQuery

Tags: jquery, hsl

How do I increase the lightness(or the `l` property) of a `hsl` color.

Ie if I have an element

```
<div class="myDiv" style="background-color:hsl(240,100%,50%)">My div</div>
```

How do I use JavaScript or jQuery to change the lightness of the `div`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple choices, but here's one that changes only the lightness:

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('myDiv')[0];
var newLightness = '70%';
div.outerHTML = div.outerHTML.replace(/(hsl\(.*?,.*?,).*?(\))/, '$1' + newLightness + '$2');
```

This will edit only the lightness on the div's outerHTML.

Explanation:
The HSL property cannot be fetched from the `style` attribute due to w3's standarts, but the HSL is still present in the DOM, so we just replace the current's div 3rd parameter to the HSL function in the inline style, we use regex with capturing groups to catch what comes before and after the lightness parameter,  and by that replacing only the lightness.
Even if the element has inner elements with the HSL inline style, only the first one will be changed, because the `g` flag wasn't specified in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can change whole style attribute with with jquery. Keep in mind it replaces everything inside style="..." and for every element with myDiv class, if you need to change only one, give it an id and target that.

```js
function myFunction() {
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".myDiv").css('cssText',"background-color:hsl(240,100%,90%)");
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class ="myDiv" style="background-color:hsl(240,100%,50%)">My div</div>
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thank you.But is it possible to only chnage the l property because I am getting the color from a backend code which I cannot edit,Something like {$background-color)

Comment: @Newbie That doesn't make sense to me. It doesn't matter from where you getting your  style applied to element. This will change it. You just need to copy whole style that is being applied, copy it to this JS function and alter part you want to change. But there is other answer here changing only what you want so see if that helps, I  will leave my answer as it is.

Comment: The reason why I dont want to copy the entire style is because the color can be changed at any time by the backend designers and the color is the global color theme so I dont wnat to have to be changing the color manulaay all the time

Comment: @Newbie Makes sense, sorry for not answering correctly the question asked.